# Full width divisions using HTML5 and CSS3 (responsive)

Tags: html, css, width

I am relatively new to StackOverflow and am experiencing some difficulties while making a webpage

So what I require is a one page website divided into different sections, which are full-width divs (i.e 100% width of the screen)and are consecutive with different background colors.

The problem I am facing is that the divs do not take up the full width of the screen and have white space not only on the sides, but also between 2 divs
Also, when the window size reduces, the gap between divs increases

The desired result is as observed in the following websites:

http://classrebels.com/ 
http://startbootstrap.com/templates/freelancer/

The code I am using is as follows:

i) HTML:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <div class="full" id="one">
    <h1>Just something</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="full" id="two">
    <h1>Just something</h1>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

ii) The CSS:

```
    .full{
    width= 100%;
     }
    #one{
     background-color: #fff;
    }  
    #two{
     background-color: #f13;
    }
```

Please do tell me where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/JRYh2/)**

html

```
<div class="full" id="one">
     <h1>Just something</h1>
</div>
<div class="full" id="two">
     <h1>Just something</h1>
</div>
```

css

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0; /* default margin set to 0 */
    padding:0; /* default padding set to 0 */
}
.full {
    width: 100%;
}
#one {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 50%; /* whatever you want to give height */
}
#two {
    background-color: #f13;
    height: 50%; /* whatever you want to give height */
}
.full h1 {
    margin:0; /* default margin of h1 tag set to 0 */
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px; /* padding if you want to give spaces between borders and content of div */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cRWNv/)

To remove the default margin/padding on the viewport (which is giving you the whitespace), you need to add the following CSS:

```
html, body{
  width:100%; /* <-- also a good idea to add */
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

and change:

```
.full{
  width= 100%;
}
```

to:

```
.full{
  width:100%;
}
```

CSS style property/value pairs are seperated with a colon `:` and not an equals `=`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting margin and padding 0 in full and in body tag too
like

```
 .full
{
    width :100%;
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
     }
```

similarly your heading also takes some margin so set the margin of heading as required.
for better please consult this link [w3schools](http://w3schools.com)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the body and h1 margins, since they have default values in the browser.
I've fixed it for you in this fiddle:

```
h1{
  margin: 0px;
}
body{
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pWLgb/

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you dont give the whole div a background color but only the text.

if you ad a border you can see the real size of the div and it will fill the whole div with color.

check out the fiddle i made for that

```
 border: 1px solid black;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2h4kQ/

you can set the border to 0px so it is not shown and it will give you the right result

Answer (score 0):

The demo's that you linking to aren't using full width divs.  They actually use a full width `<section>` element which has the background color set on it.

Then, they have an inner row `<div>` which then has a container and column `<div>`.  So in the Freelancer example it looks like this:

```
<section class="success" id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>About</h2>
                    <hr class="star-light">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <p>Freelancer is a free bootstrap theme created by Start Bootstrap. The download includes the complete source files including HTML, CSS, and JavaScript as well as optional LESS stylesheets for easy customization.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <p>Whether you're a student looking to showcase your work, a professional looking to attract clients, or a graphic artist looking to share your projects, this template is the perfect starting point!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
                        <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download Theme
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Sample of the CSS:

```
section.success {
color: #fff;
background: #18bc9c;
}

.container {
width: 1170px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Download that template, it uses [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), and play around with it to get the look you want.